# Magento Checkout error

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I am using **unirgy_giftcert** gift certification plugin. 
When I use gift code during checkout, I get following error message
***Can't find implementation of payment method Unicert*** 
[image: Can't find implementation of payment method Unicert]

Order seems to be completed, because, when I go to **My Cart** page, cart is blank.
Now When I try to complete the order in back end, I get the same error.

[image: Unirgy_giftcert]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found answer of my question, after doing some R&D with my site.
Note : **If you are using unirgy_giftcert and Subscription plugin, please note, you can not buy subscription products using Gift certificate codes**
Actually, you can buy (but you must not), but, can not make full payment using gift certificate, because, it might create some problem in future devilries. 
My site is a subscription based product selling company, that is why I was getting error.

I hope this will help someone.